# JPQL Query yields no results using BETWEEN operator

Tags: jpa, jpql

When using this method:

```
    public static List<Image> listImages(double longitude, double latitude) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("select e from Image as e where e.long_ between " 
+(longitude - 0.1)+" and "+(longitude + 0.1)+ " and e.lat between "+(latitude-0.1)+" and "+(latitude+0.1)+" order by e.id desc");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Image> imageList = q.getResultList();
    System.out.println("Size: " + imageList.size());
    return imageList;
}
```

imageList comes back empty, imageList.size() returning 0.
Even though the query SHOULD return at least a few rows from my database based on the query.

I am not sure what to do, because I am getting no errors. It just comes back empty. Please let me know if I should provide something else!

Comment: What is the database type of the lat and long_ fields, what is the SQL that is generated, and what happens if you run the SQL yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised what was wrong. Just a screwup by me.

```
    public Image(String url, double longitude, double latitude, Time time) {
    this.url = url;
    this.lat = latitude;
    this.long_ = longitude;
    this.moment = time;
}
```

I misplaced longtude and latitude here, so when I insert something into the database, the longitude and latitude trade places. That's why I wasn't getting any results. Sorry!